# Word VBA Move Images and Text into a Table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to check every section of a document for images or grouped images and, if they're found, create a table with 1 row and 2 columns at the beginning of that section, where the first column will contain the text (with original formatting) and the second column will contain the images. I have converted all the images in the document to inline shapes.

Edit: In the document, there's random amounts of text (and/or other characters) before, after and in between a random amount of images. Sometimes a section has no text and only images. For each section, I would like all of the text (with original formatting and in the order in which it occurs) to be contained in the first column, and all images and grouped images (also in their same order) to be contained in the second folder. Ideally, if the only things on the page are a heading and an image, they would be put into a 1x1 table (with the heading above the image).

I've tried a few variations of this with no success. Generally stuff starts getting pretty messy because I have no idea what I'm doing. I've left out the text in this code because it was only complicating things, but I would like to move the text as well.

```
Sub ToTables()

Dim iShp As InlineShape
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

a = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Sections")
    
For i = 1 To a

Set oRng = ActiveDocument.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSection, Name:=i)
Set oRng = oRng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\section")

If Right(oRng, 1) = vbCr Then _
        oRng = Left(oRng, Len(oRng) - 1)

b = oRng.InlineShapes.Count
If b >= 1 Then
    oRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        Set oTbl = oRng.Tables.Add(oRng, 1, 2, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitContent)
        For Each iShp In oRng.InlineShapes
            iShp.Select
            Selection.Cut
            oTbl.Cell(1, 2).Range.Paste
        Next iShp
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the revised code:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Sctn As Section, Rng As Range, Tbl As Table, s As Long, w As Single
For Each Sctn In ActiveDocument.Sections
  Set Rng = Sctn.Range: w = 0
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  Set Tbl = Rng.ConvertToTable(, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=1, InitialColumnWidth:=50, AutoFit:=True)
  With Tbl
    .Columns.Add
    For s = .Range.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
      With .Range.InlineShapes(s)
        If .Width > w Then w = .Width
        .Range.Rows(1).Cells(2).Range.FormattedText = .Range.FormattedText
        .Delete
      End With
    Next
    .Columns(1).Cells.Merge
    .Columns(2).Cells.Merge
    .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
    .PreferredWidth = 100
    If w > 0 Then .Columns(2).Width = w + .LeftPadding + .RightPadding
    .Rows.HeightRule = wdRowHeightAuto
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The column should AutoFit to any InlineShapes. The relative positioning doesn't really matter, just text in column 1 and shapes in column 2. And there should be only one row. This code creates many rows - I probably should have been more specific.

Comment: «I probably should have been more specific» Indeed you should have. Try the revised code.

Comment: Alright, so I've been able to get this to work for the most part, except for one thing. Some of the text is different colours, and after being moved into the table it is all one colour. Thanks again!

Comment: In my testing, the macro has no effect on any paragraph formatting or font attributes - all are preserved.

Comment: Ya, I'm not sure what the issue was. It's working fine for me now too. Thank you.

Comment: In that case, please check the check box next to my answer, in order to mark it as an *accepted* answer so others who might be searching for similar topics can find an answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text precedes the inlineshapes:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim iShp As InlineShape
For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  With iShp.Range
    .Characters.First.Previous = vbTab
    .Start = .Paragraphs.First.Range.Start
    .ConvertToTable vbTab, 1, 2
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above code assumes there is a single character between the text & inlineshape. That character could be a space, paragraph break, line break, anything at all.

Comment: There's random amounts of text before, after and in between random amount of images. Sometimes a section has no text and only images.

Comment: Since you specified «the first column will contain the text (with original formatting)», kindly update your question to explain what determines which text (if any) should or should not be incorporated into the table with the images.

Comment: I meant all the text and images. I've updated the question to hopefully clarify things. Thanks.